# How to combine asterix syntax with table abbreviations

Tags: sql, abbreviation, tablename

Is it possible to combine * syntax with table abbreviations?

I want to do something like:

```
"SELECT subfunds.* FROM subfunds S" +
" INNER JOIN funds F ON S.id_fund = F.id" +
" WHERE F.fund_short IN('" + stSQLFundList + "')"
```

The above code gets a syntax error

> "invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "subfunds".

I already found that if I do

```
"SELECT * FROM subfunds S" +
" INNER JOIN funds F ON S.id_fund = F.id" +
" WHERE F.fund_short IN('" + stSQLFundList + "')"
```

then I get all fields from both tables rather than from the subfunds table only.

So how do I get all fields from the first table (and none of the other tables' fields) in my answer set while also being able to use the single-letter table abbreviations?

Comment: Google "SQL Injection Attack"

Comment: IF you use a **table alias**, then you need to refer to the columns you want using that alias - so use `SELECT s.* FROM subfunds s....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this and you will get all fields from subfunds.

```
"SELECT S.* FROM subfunds S" +
" INNER JOIN funds F ON S.id_fund = F.id" +
" WHERE F.fund_short IN('" + stSQLFundList + "')"
```

If you are using an alias, then you want to reference that table by it's alias.